# How to start headless browser with Selenium on Ubuntu using bash or Python

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, selenium, cron

I'm running a cron job which runs a Python script that uses Selenium. Selenium requires a display, so I've [installed Xvfb, started the display, and firefox](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/):

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
firefox
```

This works when I run these commands in the console, but I want to be able to do it with cron. How can I do this? If I run the virtual display as the main user, will they have access to the virtual display when it's needed by Python script/Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use selenium Ghost Driver(it's running [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)).